# Get many cities using Forecast API

Tags: android, api

I'm trying to develope an app using Forecast API. But this api just allow to get data from only one City by get a latitude and longtitude. This is my code

```
final double latitude=21.0260;
final double longtitude=105.8471;
String forecastUrl="https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"+apiKey+"/"+latitude+","+longtitude;
```

.This code will return data from only Hanoi city. how to get data from 2 or more cities by only use this latidude and longtitude?
This is my called function but i don't know how to change too loop because iam calling GetForecast() function:

```
    final double[] latitudes={21.0260,12.0260,21.1260};
    final double[] longtitudes={23.0260,42.0260,51.1260};

    mRefreshImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getForecast(latitudes,longtitudes);
        }
    });
    getForecast(latitudes,longtitudes);
Log.d(TAG, "MainUI code is running");
}

private void getForecast(double[] latitude,double[] longtitude) {
    String apiKey="a424ddd79338808311d0a6197a12731e";
    String forecastUrl="https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"+apiKey+"/"+latitude+","+longtitude;

    if (isNetWorkAvailable()) {
        toogleRefresh();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request req = new Request.Builder()
                .url(forecastUrl)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(req);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toogleRefresh();
                    }
                });  alertUser();
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toogleRefresh();
                    }
                });
                try {
                    String jsonData=response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        mCurrentWeather=getCurrentDetail(jsonData);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateDisplay();
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        alertUser();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception  caught:", e);
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception  caught:", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_network_unavailable,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

updateDetail:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    mTemperatureLabel.setText(mCurrentWeather.getTemperature() + "");
    mHumidityValue.setText(mCurrentWeather.getHumidity() + "");
    mTimeLabel.setText( "At "+ mCurrentWeather.getFormattedTime()+" it will be");
    mPrecipeValue.setText(mCurrentWeather.getPrecipChance()+"");
    mSummaryValue.setText(mCurrentWeather.getSumary());
    Drawable drawable=getResources().getDrawable(mCurrentWeather.getIconId());
    mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

getCurrentDetails() :

```
private CurrentWeather getCurrentDetail(String jsonData) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject forecast= new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timeZone=forecast.getString("timezone");
    Log.i(TAG,"From Json" + timeZone);
    JSONObject currently=forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
    CurrentWeather currentWeather= new CurrentWeather();
    currentWeather.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
    currentWeather.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
    currentWeather.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
    currentWeather.setPrecipChance(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
    currentWeather.setSumary(currently.getString("summary"));
    currentWeather.setTemperature(currently.getDouble("temperature"))   ;
    currentWeather.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    Log.d(TAG,currentWeather.getFormattedTime());
    return currentWeather;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make array of latitudes and longitudes then fetch url by using for loop.

**eg:-**

```
final double[] latitudes={21.0260,12.0260,21.1260};
final double[] longitudes={23.0260,42.0260,51.1260};

String[] forecastUrls;

for(int i;i<latitudes.lenght;i++){

   forecastUrls[i] = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"+apiKey+"/"+latitudes[i]+","+longtitude[i];
}
```

**Updated :-**

```
 mRefreshImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i;i<latitudes.length;i++){
              getForecast(latitudes[i],longtitudes[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: After that how can i call 1st city and 2nd city to two different Textview1 and Textview2? Can you suggest me more clearly?

Comment: How you calling without array (in question) ?

Comment: ` OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();<br/>
            Request req = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();<br/>
            Call call = client.newCall(req);`<br/>
i'm calling like this

Comment: Add this code inside `for  loop`. Then replace `forecastUrl` to `forecastUrls[i]`

Comment: Shoud i add more TextView to show data from the 2nd and 3rd City to updateDetails()??

Comment: Yes... Add more textview.

Comment: but can u give me solution to show? I just added the Textview2 to show another Temperature, can u show me on code?